# How to align my Login Form using MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Does anyone how to help me align my login page. I've tried to align my login page adding CSS code on my bootstrap but nothing happen.

Here's my code on Login.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Email)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Email)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)<br />
    @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)<br />
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Log In</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Registration")
    </p>
}
```

Am I missing anything here?
Cause the output on my webpage is like this i want to put it on the middle.
any suggestion? Thanks in advance

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Probably want to look at the login examples: [Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/signin/) or [Bootstrap 4](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/)

Comment: is this bootstrap free??

Comment: Yes. Those are examples from the docs.

Comment: I don't want to be spoiled but Thanks. is there anyway i can do it my own way? or any other tips to make my login center?

Comment: bootstrap libraries are free, and also gets included with ASP.NET MVC by default. you want to design your pages without the use of bootstrap?

Comment: @Nirman Thanks, yes i want to design my page without bootstrap. all i need is a logic or simple code ex: align="center" to make my login in center. i know it's the default code for the landing page of my login is on left. (confusing) sorry

Comment: Never mind actually thanks for the Help. i resolve my own problem. i used <center> tag </center> to make it  in the middle. and works perfectly for me.

Comment: Hey @SillyHead Good to know that you found a solution. For future reference, please note that aligning stuff on a web page requires CSS. You'd get much better response if you ask such questions with CSS tag